# When Session time-out occurred, preRenderView of previous screen is executed

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-3

When forward method in the filter executed, 
preRenderView of previous screen is executed if a screen transfer in the session time-out state.

ex)Flow of processing
Session time-out: Login -> Start(session time-out) -> Error
(Default:Login -> Start -> End)
When Start transition to Error, preRenderView of Start is executed.
Isn't preRenderView of Error called in usual?

I think the SpringBeanFacesELResolver class is the cause.
Is it right to do such behavior?
Please tell me the cause and a plan to avoid.

It's being checked in the following state (excerpt).

- Spring 3.2.5-RELEASE
- JDK 1.7.0_76
- JSF 2.1
- WebLogic 12.1.3

LoginAction.java

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope("request")
public class LoginAction implements java.io.Serializable {

    public LoginAction() {
    }

    public String login() {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        // The STATUS attribute is set in a session.
        session.setAttribute("STATUS", "LOGIN");
        return "/Sample/start.xhtml";
    }

}
```

StartAction.java

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope("request")
public class StartAction implements java.io.Serializable {

    public StartAction() {
    }

    public void preRenderView(javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent event)
            throws javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException {
        // Some process
    }

    public void preRenderViewOnSystemError(javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent event)
            throws AbortProcessingException, IOException {
        // Some process
    }

    public String toEnd() {
        return "toEnd";
    }
}
```

TestFilter.java

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
            HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
            // When the STATUS attribute can't get a session, a forward is executed.
            String status = (String)session.getAttribute("STATUS");
            if (status == null || "".equals(status)) {
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/faces/Sample/error.xhtml");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

start.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
        <title>Sample Start</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:event listener="#{startAction.preRenderView}" type="preRenderView"/>
        <h:form action="" id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h:commandButton action="#{startAction.toEnd}" id="toEnd" type="submit" value="End"></h:commandButton>
            ::
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

error.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
        <title>Sample Error</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:event listener="#{startAction.preRenderViewOnSystemError}" type="preRenderView"/>
        <h:form action="" id="form1" method="post">
            Error
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/componentScanSettings.xml
        /WEB-INF/datasource-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/Sample/Sample-faces-config.xml, /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Test</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.xxx.filter.TestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Test</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/Sample/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- The expiration date of a session is made short. -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Sample-faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<faces-config 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd" 
    version="2.0">

    <navigation-rule>
        <description>Start</description>
        <display-name>Start</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/Sample/start.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
             <from-outcome>toEnd</from-outcome>
             <to-view-id>/Sample/end.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

componentScanSettings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean
    xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd'
    xmlns:context='http://www.springframework.org/schema/context' 
    xmlns='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans'
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package='com.xxx' />
</bean>
```

datasource-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" order="100" />

    <bean id="targetDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource" ref="targetDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="filterMultipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize">
            <value>100000</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxInMemorySize">
            <value>10240</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I did not get the question thoroughly in conjunction with, "*Forward in a `Filter`*". Just some outsiders things : `MultipartFilter` is part of Spring MVC. How do you get it to work in conjunction with JSF? An `<h:form>` does not have the `name` attribute (nor `action`/`method`). It is only `id`.

Comment: You should show exactly how you're performing the navigation. The multipartfilter looks suspect (the documentation says it's not to be combined with another multipart-capable MVC framework, like Mojarra); you should confirm if that filter is the problem, by elimination. The EL resolver is harmless and is fairly standard for integrating JSF and Spring. Also, like Tiny says, your h:form as it is simply won't work

Comment: Thank you very much, Tiny and kolossus.
The information which wasn't enough (Filter) was added.
It'll be confirmed now whether it's a problem by a presence of Filter.